# Post action not receiving Navigation property of object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

Following is how my model is defined.

```
public class Manager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public int DeparmentID { get; set; }

    public double Salary { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Subordiates { get; set; }
}
```

When I pass the `Manager` object in my MVC edit view, it does successfully pass all `Subordiates`. But my edit view doesn't have to do anything to the `Subordiates` and so I don't do anything to it in the view. But during Post action, I got its collection is 0, whereas it should have the items as they are untouched.

Can anyone please help me what could be wrong here?

Comment: Share your code. The model that you receive in your post is not the same object that you passed to the view - it's a new object bound to the values that were posted in the form. You should be using view models and retrieving your actual data entities again in the POST controller action.

Comment: Can you please update your question with some code? It is harder to provide some direction without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not use the collection in your view, the values *won't* be posted back to the controller. This is default behavior. You will have to re-populate the `Subordiates` collection if you want the post action to return to the view.